# Standard nodejs http.get return timeout after moving to Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

Moved my app from `Fedora` Linux to latest `Ubuntu 12.04`. Both machines are behind a corporate web proxy. The node version on `Ubuntu` is `0.6.6`. Could this be a `Ubuntu 12.04` specific problem? Does other see this as well?